# Get date from filename and delete the file if the date is before a certain date

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files in multiple sub-folders like this:

```
folder1
 - folder1a
  - dira
     -dirb
       - folder-1999-07-05.txt
       - folder-1999-07-04.txt
       - folder-1999-07-03.txt
       - 1999-07-02_a2-abcd.txt

folder2
 - folder2a
  - dira
     -dirb
       - folder-1995-07-05.txt
       - folder-1995-07-04.txt
       - folder-1995-07-03.txt
       - 1995-07-02_a2-abcd.txt
```

Now if I want to delete files older than a certain date (e.g. 1996-01), what would be the best/most efficient approach?

Comment: What do you mean 'older'? Creation date? Modification date? Access date? Look into the find(1) and stat(1) utilities. And show what you gotten so far.

Comment: Right, which date  are you referring to.

Comment: What I meant was if any of those files had a date in their name (1995-07 for the file 1995-07-02_a2-abcd.txt) which is a date prior to the date (for e.g. 1996-01), then that file would be deleted. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find` and a while read loop. In your examples the dates are already in the file names, so this should work.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Populate the array named folders with folders.
folders=(folder1 folder2 folder3 another_folder new_folder)

##: Set the date limit in a variable.
limit=1996-01

##: Loop through the output of find using a while read loop.
while IFS=  read -rd '' files; do
  files=${files##*/}
  files=${files#*[!0-9]-}
  if [[ $files < $limit ]]; then ##: If the date in the filenames is older than the set limit.
    echo rm -rf "$files"  ##: Delete the files
  else
    echo "$files is newer than $limit"
  fi   ##: Use find to look for files ending in .txt
done < <(find "${folders[@]}" -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

An alternative is to use `BASH_REMATCH` to extract the date from the file names.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

folders=(folder1 folder2 folder3 another_folder new_folder)
limit=1996-01

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do  ##: BASH_REMATCH to extract the dates.
  if [[ $files =~ .*([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}).*\.txt$ ]]; then
    if  [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} < $limit ]]; then  ##: The > inside [[ ]] does the trick.
      echo rm -rf "$files"
    else
      echo "$files is newer than $limit"
    fi
  fi
done < <(find "${folders[@]}" -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

---

- That will just show you what it going to be removed/executed, remove the `echo` in front of the `rm` if you think the output is correct, and make sure to have a backup of the files just in case.
- If there are more files ending in `*.txt` on all the sub folders then you need to specify how deep the directory you're going to delete the files instead of `folder1` you need to do `folder1/subfolder/another/folder` until you reach the sub folder you're interested in.

Comment: **prior** means *earlier in time*.

Comment: And, the first script will remove all files whose name start with `folder-`; take a closer look at OP's example

Comment: It was mentioned at the post. `Now if I want to delete files older than a certain date (e.g. 1996-01), what would be the best/most efficient approach?`

Comment: Yes, the script will remove all files that is higher that 1996-06, the `echo` is there so if the OP says the output is not right then I will fix the issue.

Comment: 1995-01 is older than 1996-01, 1997-01 is not. Both scripts above will leave 1995-01... and remove 1997-01...

Comment: Some files in OP's examples have `folder-` prefix, so `[[ ${files##*/} > $limit ]]` will compare folder-1995-01... to 1996-01, and thus evaluate to true; it won't even take the date part into consideration, as f > 1