# How to delete files older than a certain date in file name in Ubuntu

Tags: rm

I have files in a single folder with the following naming convention: `bkup_yyyymmdd.log`

So there are, for example, the following files listed in reverse name order in the folder:

```
bkup_20210513.log

bkup_20210512.log

bkup_20210511.log

bkup_20210510.log

bkup_20210509.log
```

I'd like to delete files including and older than `bkup_20210510.log`. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419206/get-date-from-filename-and-delete-the-file-if-the-date-is-before-a-certain-date), and whilst it seems very similar, there appears to be some 'argument' amongst those answering and I'm completely lost as to which answer is correct.  Hence my re-posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following based on the answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/245087/find-files-their-name-is-smaller-or-greater-than-a-given-parameter) question :

```
weekago=`date -d -1week +%Y%m%d` 

OLDERTHAN='./bkup_'$weekago'.log' 

for fname in ./bkup_*.log; do test "$fname" "<" "$OLDERTHAN" && rm
 "$fname"; done
```

Works a treat.